# Difference between File and DocumentFile in Java

Tags: java, android, file, android-support-library, documentfile

What's exactly the difference between a `java.util.File` and a `android.support.v4.provider.DocumentFile` in Java Android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short:

**File** is the "normal" Java file that one would normally know if even he never touched Android - i.e. abstraction for accessing underlying OS's files/directories.

**DocumentFile** was introduced to further abstract this in Android's Storage Access Framework (SAF) - it is either backed by "normal" file or by another abstraction called DocumentProvider https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html and could be used to access both types of files in a more generic way. It is part of Google's continuing effort to 'hide' the underlying OS file/directory structure.

One approach would be to use both File (when accessing disk/card files) or DocumentFile (when accessing files backed from ContentProvider) but the more "modern" way would be to use always DocumentFile, which can represent a normal File by using `fromFile(File)`